# Multiple insert in already existing table with missing identity column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-insert

In SQL Server, I am trying to insert 375 rows into an already existing table.

The table doesn't have an identity column, but the `ID` column is unique and I want to enter unique id for each 375 rows. I tried doing `max(id)+1` but for all 375 rows, it inserted same id and data got messed up. I can't alter the `id` column because table got more than million rows.

Code as below:

```
declare @id int

set @id = select max(id) from tablename;

Insert into tablename (id, column 1, column 2, column 3, ..... column 20)
    select @id + 1, column1, column2, column 3, ........, column 20
    from tablename1
    where column15 IN (1,2,3,4,.........,375)
```

Comment: create `SEQUENCE`

Comment: can you please explain little bit more?

Comment: You may be able to do something like this... `select @id + ROW_NUMBER() Over (Partition By Column1 Order by Column1) `

Comment: The table geting more than a million rows don't means you cannot change that column merely means changing that column can take some (maybe a lot) time. Cannot you use a weeked maintenance window? Also creating a sequence is not that demanding

Comment: No need for sequence here @jean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just use `row_number`.

```
declare @id int

set @id = (select max(id) from tablename)

Insert into tablename (id, column 1, column 2, column 3, ..... column 20)

select
    row_number() over (order by (select null)) + @id,
    column1, 
    column2, 
    column 3, 
    ........, 
    column 20
from tablename1
```